# Why getElementsByClassName doesn't work on xhr reponseXML

Tags: javascript

Why xhr.responseXML.getElementsByClassName('clazz') doesn't work?

Here is the js:

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            var happiness = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByClassName('clazz');

            //Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined
            console.log("happiness ? " + happiness[0].innerHTML);
         }
    };

    //xhr.overrideMimeType("application/xml");
    xhr.open("GET", "xhr.php", true);
    xhr.send(null);
```

xhr.php contains the following:

```
<?php

header('Content-type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8');

echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> \n";

?>



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<title>I'm the XHR response</title>

</head>

<body>



<div class="clazz">xhr happiness</div>



<div id="x" class="y"></div>



</body>

</html>
```

can you please explain the following output in the Chrome console?

```
xhr.responseXML.getElementById('x')
<div id="x" class="y"></div>

xhr.responseXML.getElementsByClassName('y')
[]
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` is not a base DOM method, it's a method of the DOM HTML extension. There is no concept of classes in XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xhr.responseXML is XML nodes and not HTML elements which means that class attribute has not a special meaning.

However, when I added xmlns declaration to the html tag, the getElementsByClassName on responseXML just worked (tested on Chrome).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Answer (score 3):

While getElementsByClassName() wont work, getElementsByTagName() will; and tags have Attributes.

```
var XMLtagDIV = xhr.getElementsByTagName('div');
var XMLclassY = []; 
var counter = 0;         //Keep class array incrementally uniform e.g. 0,1,2,3,4...
 for(i=0; i<XMLtagDIV.length; i++) 
{ 
  if(XMLtagDIV[i].getAttribute('class') == 'y') { 
   counter++;                            
   XMLclassY[counter] = XMLclassY;  }    
}
```

Now the array variable XMLclassY will act just as getElementsByClass(); should.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's XML, not HTML. You also won't find `innerHTML` properties on your nodes.